# How do I write a Python code for partial fraction decomposition without using "apart"?

Tags: python, partial, decomposition

So I am very unexperienced with Python, I know basically nothing, and our teacher gave us the task to write a code that makes a partial fraction decomposition with this function:

[image: function]

I don't really know how to start or even how to define that function. I tried this at first: `

```
def function(x):
    a = (x^4)-(3*x^2)+x+5
    b = (x^11)-(3*x^10)-(x^9)+(7*x^8)-(9*x^7)+(23*x^6)-(11*x^5)-(3*x^4)-(4*x^3)-(32*x^2)-16
    return a/b
```

But our maths script says that we need to split up the denominator and then make a system of equations out of it and solve it.
[image: how to split it up]
So I was thinking about defining each part of the function itself and then make a function somehow like a = 7*x and use it like f(x) = b/a^7 if this works but I don't really know. We are unfortunately not allowed to use "apart" which I think is a sympy-function?

Thank you so much in advance!

Sincerely, Phie

Addition: So after a few hours of trying I figured this. But I am very sure that this is not the way to do it. Also it tells me that variable l is not defined in z and I am sure that all the others aren't as well. I don't know what to do.

```
def function(x):
global a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v
a = (x^4)-(3*x^2)+x+5

b = 11
c = 10
d = 9
e = 8
f = 7
g = 6
h = 5
i = 4
j = 3
k = 2
l = x**b
m = 3*x**c
n = x**d
o = 7*x**e
p = 9*x**f
q = 23*x**g
r = 11*x**h
s = 3*x**i
t = 4*x**j
u = 32*x**k
v = 16

return a/(l-m-n+o-p+q-r-s-t-u-v)

print("We are starting the partial fraction decomposition with this 
function: (x^4)-(3*x^2)+x+5 / (x^11)-(3*x^10)-(x^9)+(7*x^8)-(9*x^7)+ 
(23*x^6)-(11*x^5)-(3*x^4)-(4*x^3)-(32*x^2)-16")

z = l-m-n+o-p+q-r-s-t-u-v
while c >= 0:
    c = c-1
    z = z-l

while d >= 0:
    d = d-1
    z = z-m

while e >= 0:
    e = e-1
    z = z-n 

while f >= 0:
    f = f-1
    z = z+o 

while g >= 0:
    g = g-1
    z = z-p

while h >= 0:
    h = h-1
    z = z+q

while i >= 0:
    i = i-1
    z = z-r

while j >= 0:
    j = j-1
    z = z-s

while k >= 0:
    k = k-1
    z = z-t

print(z)
```

Comment: Can you share the actual task (maybe with inputs and desired outputs)? I don't think your teacher wants you to write code that only works for one input (that function) but maybe something more generic...

Comment: Also, remember that `^` is the XOR operation in Python, not the power operation (which is `**`)

Comment: Well the actual task is in german but here is what it says:

Split up this rational function (from the picture above) in partial fractions, without using the command "apart".
Note: You can use the commands "roots" and "solve_undetermined_coeffs".

So I think it's okay to make it only work with this function?? But I'm not quite sure.
Also I just looked up what XOR is and I didn't mean that, I meant power (x²). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: okay it can be specific:) i just asked
@AKX (forgot to tag you so you would see it)

Answer (score 0):

Since I just solved this myself, here's some input:

Let `poly = function()` for your function, although be careful to replace `^` with `**`. Include both `from sympy import *` and `from sympy.abc import a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, x`.

Using `factor(exp)` you can find all the roots of your function, use these to define the 11 terms `term_1 = a/(x-2)`, `term_2 = b/(x2-)**2`, ... , `term_6 = (f*x + g)/(x**2 +1)`, ..., `term_8 = (j*x + k)/(x**2 + 1)` (you get the gist). Define `your_sum = term_1 + ... + term_8`, `eq = Eq(your_sum, poly)`

Define the variable `your_sum = sum(term_1, ..., term_8)`, and use `solve_undetermined_coeffs(eq, [a,b, ..., k], x)))` to get the result.